# 'at' command not working

Tags: bash, time

I want to run a backup command at a specific time in bash. Only issue is the `at` command doesn't seem to work. By this I mean it does not run the command at the specific time

I have tried to use the commands posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734365/run-a-command-at-a-specific-time).

If the at command doesn't work are there any other suggestions?

I am trying to run a custom command I put in the /bin directory called `backup`.
If it helps I am running OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

**Edit**

Found out the issue.

Some reason my command will only work outside a script. Hmm

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? What happens when you run the command? What messages are printed? And please show the actual command you try in your question.

Comment: What do you mean by “it doesn't work“? do you get an error message? if yes, it would be nice to include it too (after reading and understanding it, of course). With so little information we won't be able to help you.

Comment: It does not run the command at the specific time

Comment: Are you sure the system time is correct or what you expect?

Comment: Here is the command. `at 18:10 < /bin/backup` and `backup | at 18:11` `backup` did not happen at 18:10 or 18:11

Comment: Where is the system log? Yes i did type both commands

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That just give `at: garbled time`

Comment: At least you do have an error message! please edit your question, including your exact command and this error message!

Comment: If you have an answer, add an answer, rather than embedding the answer in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

From the `man atrun`:

> The atrun utility runs commands queued by at(1).  It is invoked periodically by launchd(8) as specified in the
>   com.apple.atrun.plist property list.  By default the property list contains the **Disabled** key set to true, so
>   atrun is never invoked.
>
> Execute the following command as root to enable atrun:
>
> launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason why.
It is because the command for some reason didn't work (it did before though)